# How to configure the TSLint plugin for sonarqube in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, typescript, sonarqube, tslint

I installed the TSLint plugin for sonarqube in my Jenkins server https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin. But its not described the git page as to how to set the configuration properties and values. How to specify the source directory, how to ignore test directory are two main concerns. Can some one provide an example configuration property set with basic configurations that I can use in my Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sonar-project.properties file for configuration.  There are some example projects provided by [SonarSource](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/javascript/javascript-sonar-runner-lcov) that might be helpful.

Here's a quick example of how you could set the source directory, test directory, and files to ignore:

```
sonar.sources=client-app/src
sonar.tests=client-app/test
sonar.exclusions=client-app/node_modules, client-app/lib
```

UPDATE:

The sample projects have moved [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/blob/master/sonarqube-scanner/sonar-project.properties).  There isn't a JavaScript example anymore, but the syntax would be the same for any language.

The documentation for parameters that can be set is currently located here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: broken link :( "SonarSource"